# Get the next day name after the day name in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, dayofweek, weekday

I am looking for a formula that will return the long day name after the long day name in another cell. So if A1 contains Monday, I want the formula to return Tuesday for B1. This is part of a larger IF formula, so I may want C1 to return something else. I've got the rest of it figure out except how to get the day name after the day in A1.

I've tried =text(A1+1,"dddd"), but that returned a #VALUE! error.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,index(text(sequence(8),"dddd")),index(Σ,xmatch(A1,Σ)+1))
```

[image]